# MongoDb get collection sorted by filter

Tags: mongodb

Good evening everyone

I have a problem to get the data in the same order I'm trying to filter/fetch it.

There are two different collections. `user` and `records`. Each `user` has a property called `liked`, which is an array of objects, containing a `recordId` and a `timestamp`.

Now processing the data in the API, I'm fetching the `user` and sort the `liked` array by the `timestamp`.

The fastest way to get the records would be

```js
const releases = await Release.find({
  "tracks._id": { $in: likedTracks },
})
 .limit(limit * 1)
 .skip((page - 1) * limit)
 .exec();
```

This would give me the releases but in the order of how they are stored in the collection – **but not in the order I've "requested" them.**

I've tried to keep the order in a less traditional way

```js
for (let i = (page - 1) * limit; i < page * limit; i++) {
  let release = await Release.find({"tracks._id": likedTracks[i]});
  releases = [...releases, release];
}
```

But this is way too slow and creating unnecessary requests.

What's the best approach here? Any hints where I can find this in the documentation? I was unable to find it.

Thanks a lot!
Phil

edit:
added example

```
{ "tracks._id": { $in: ["3", "1", "2"] } }
```

Will currently return (because it's stored in that order in the collection):

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1000,
    "tracks": [
      {
        "_id": "1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": 2000,
    "tracks": [
      {
        "_id": "2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": 3000,
    "tracks": [
      {
        "_id": "3"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

expected return:

```
[
  {
    "_id": 3000,
    "tracks": [
      {
        "_id": "3"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": 1000,
    "tracks": [
      {
        "_id": "1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": 2000,
    "tracks": [
      {
        "_id": "2"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/PCjPAzkqY0d

Comment: Can you add some sample json documents and the expected output so we can try to replicate the issue?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @ray. I've just added some json.